# onchange javascript to submit form breaks in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, form-submit, onchange

i was using a javascript like this...

```
<select onchange="document.langForm.submit();" ... >
```

but that broke when i started using jquerymobile.

i know this issue has come up 100 times before. but hyperlinks to prior cases wont help here because i have already read dozens and unfortunately i am just not smart enough to understand any of those other discussions. seriously. i am totally confused.

on the other hand, i have made time to make a REALLY, REALLY simple example to show the headache i have. so, if someone can tell me exactly how to fix these two pages, that would be very much appreciated.

http://activemetrics.ch/test/en.html

http://activemetrics.ch/test/de.html

notice that you can load either one of these in your browser and then switch to the other page by changing the selection in the select list. however, after you get to the second page, you can not use a similar action to get back to the first page.

yes, this has to with ajax. i know that much. but what is the very best way for me to fix the problem right here on these 2 pages to allow users to switch back and forth between the two pages easily?

all suggestions are welcome.

thanks very much to anyone who is spending some of their brain waves considering this for me!

-jd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Description :

To understand this situation you need to understand how **`jQuery Mobile`** works. It uses ajax to load other pages.

First page is loaded normally. Its **`HEAD`** and **`BODY`** is loaded into the **`DOM`**, and they are there to await other content. When second page is loaded, only its **`BODY`** content is loaded into the **`DOM`**.

From what I have so in your answer you understand this but you had make a mistake. There are 2 html files: **`en.html`** and **`de.html`** but their names are not slightly important. What is important is page id's or id's attribute of **`data-role="page"`** div. In your case you have 2 pages with a same div and with a same select id.  Because both of them are loaded into the **`DOM`** event binding will always go to the first loaded page.

What you need to to is use unique id for your pages and your select boxes.

### Working example :

**en.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
        <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>      
        <div data-role="page" id="sbePage1">
            <h3>this is english</h3>      
            <form name="langForm" id="langForm" action="BookNow.asp?" method="get" style="margin-top:0px auto">
                <select data-inline="true" name="lang" id="langId" data-native-menu="false" >
                    <option value="1972" SELECTED>Something Already Selected</option>
                    <option value="1973">Some Sort of Change</option>
                </select>
            </form> 
            <script>
                $(document).on('pageinit', '#sbePage1' ,function () {   
                    $(document).off('change', '#langId').on('change', '#langId',function (event) {          
                        $.mobile.changePage('de.html', {
                            type: 'get',
                            data: ''
                        });
                    });
                });   
            </script>           
        </div><!-- /page -->      
    </body>
</html>
```

**de.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
        <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>       
        <div data-role="page" id="sbePage2">
            <h3>this is german</h3>      
            <form name="langForm2" id="langForm2" action="BookNow.asp?" method="get" style="margin-top:0px auto">
                <select data-inline="true" name="lang" id="langId2" data-native-menu="false" >
                    <option value="1972" SELECTED>Something Already Selected</option>
                    <option value="1973">Something Else</option>
                </select>
            </form> 
            <script>
                $(document).on('pageinit', '#sbePage2' ,function () {
                    $(document).off('change', '#langId2').on('change', '#langId2',function (event) {            
                        $.mobile.changePage('en.html', {
                            type: 'get',
                            data: ''
                        });
                    });
                });             
            </script>
        </div><!-- /page -->     
    </body>
</html>
```

### Edit :

While I understand your wish, I still must tell you that it is impossible. You can't have 2 pages with a same id with jQuery Mobile in your current example. Think about it, you will have 2 pages with an identical id loaded into the DOM. Each time you try to access the page DIV you will ALWAYS access the first page because it is first in line.

If you want to create a multilingual page you don't need several html pages. Just look for a good jQuery multilingual plugin.

On the other hand you can do what you want if you turn ajax off but you will loose animated transitions.

### Example without ajax but where pages have same id

**en.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="text/javascript">
          $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
          });
    </script>   
    <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="sbePage1en">
<h3>this is english</h3>      
            <form name="langFormEn" id="langFormEn" action="BookNow.asp?" method=get style="margin-top:0px auto">
                <select data-inline="true" name="lang" id="langId" data-native-menu="false" >
                    <option value="1972" SELECTED>Something Already Selected</option>
                    <option value="1973">Some Sort of Change</option>
                </select></form> 
            <script>
                $("#sbePage1en").live('pageshow', function () {
                    $('#langFormEn').bind('change', function (event) {
                        $.mobile.changePage('de.html', {
                            type: 'get',
                            data: ''
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>               
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

**de.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="text/javascript">
          $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
          });
    </script>       
    <script                 src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="sbePage1de">
<h3>this is german</h3>      
            <form name="langFormDe" id="langFormDe" action="BookNow.asp?" method=get style="margin-top:0px auto">
                <select data-inline="true" name="lang" id="langId" data-native-menu="false" >
                    <option value="1972" SELECTED>Something Already Selected</option>
                    <option value="1973">Something Else</option>
                </select></form> 
<script>
    $("#sbePage1de").live('pageshow', function () {
        $('#langFormDe').bind('change', function (event) {
            $.mobile.changePage('en.html', {
                type: 'get',
                data: ''
            });
        });
    });
</script>               
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Gajotres, Thanks very much for your input. I tried to update the html according to your suggestion and it seems to act the same as before. The two pages have separate ids now. Or did I misunderstand the change you were proposing? BTW, I strongly prefer to make this work while keeping all IDs the same because we are really talking about the same exact content here but in two different flavors/languages. It seems strange/inconvenient to make different IDs all over the place just because the text will be in one language or another.

Comment: I have added new content to my answer. Take a look.

Comment: thanks! i can see that your example is working exactly as i requested. i will study this html and also your comments to try to understand the issues as well as possible. THANKS!

Comment: Take a look at my second example (at the end), it is your code but with an ajax turned off.